# Get the integer in between two values

Tags: python, integer

For some coordinate processing I need to be able to find the integers in between 2 values. I know you can use `range()` for this, but I need it to work even when you switch the 2 values around. `range(x, y)` won't give the same results as `range(y, x)`. Is there a trick to do this?

EDIT: Torxed's comment was exactly what i needed: range(min(x, y), max(x, y))

Comment: Couldn't you use an `if` statement to check which value is larger and then perform a call accordingly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and [what types of questions can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what types should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: `range(min(x, y), max(x, y))`

Comment: Or `range(*sorted([x, y]))`

Comment: @ThomasNL are your values in a list or just like 0,1,2,3,4 or with a step as in range()

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "between"? And please provide examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `3` different options that have been suggested:

As proposed in [`@Torxed's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992998/get-the-integer-in-between-two-values/46993301#comment80932461_46992998):

```
range(min(x, y), max(x, y))
```

As proposed in [`@tobias_k's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992998/get-the-integer-in-between-two-values/46993301#comment80932476_46992998):

```
range(*sorted([x, y]))
```

Or mine, using a `ternary` condition:

```
range(x, y) if x < y else range(y, x)
```

Comment: can't yet. Account is too young :p

Comment: @ThomasNL Don't worry, get asking more questions and answering others then! **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't quite sure what's asked and just scribbled some weird code.

Both approaches can be useful depending on whether we want to keep the "discarding the 'b'" behaviour.

```
range(2,5)
#[2, 3, 4]
range(5,2,-1)
#[5, 4, 3]
range(5,2,2 * (5<2) - 1)
#[5, 4, 3]

##### Approach A
a = 5;b = 2
range(a, b, 2*(a<b) -1 )
#[5, 4, 3]

a = 2; b = 5
range(a, b, 2*(a<b) -1 )
#[2, 3, 4]


##### Approach B from @tobias_k
a = 5;b = 2
range(*sorted([a,b]))
#[2, 3, 4]

a = 2;b = 5
range(*sorted([a,b]))
#[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: So... what are you trying to tell us? Note that `range(x, y, 1)` is not the same as `range(y, x, -1)`